# Is it really slow to handle text file(more than 10K lines) with shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, text, awk

I have a file with more than 10K lines of record. 
Within each line, there are two date+time info. Below is an example:
"aaa bbb ccc 170915 200801 12;ddd e f; g; hh; 171020 122030 10; ii jj kk;"
I want to filter out the lines the days between these two dates is less than 30 days. 
Below is my source code:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
echo $filename
touch filterfile
totalline=`wc -l $filename | awk '{print $1}'`
i=0
j=0
echo $totalline lines
while read -r line
do
  i=$[i+1]
  if [ $i -gt $[j+9] ]; then
    j=$i
    echo $i
  fi
  shortline=`echo $line | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{6\}\)[ ][0-9]\{6\}.*\([0-9]\{6\}\)[ ][0-9]\{6\}.*/\1 \2/'`
  date1=`echo $shortline | awk '{print $1}'`
  date2=`echo $shortline | awk '{print $2}'`
  if [ $date1 -gt 700000 ]
  then
    continue 
  fi
  d1=`date -d $date1 +%s`
  d2=`date -d $date2 +%s`
  diffday=$[(d2-d1)/(24*3600)]
  #diffdays=`date -d $date2 +%s` - `date -d $date1 +%s`)/(24*3600)
  if [ $diffday -lt 30 ]
  then
    echo $line >> filterfile
  fi
done < "$filename"
```

I am running it in cywin. It took about 10 second to handle 10 lines. I use     echo $i to show the progress.

Is it because i am using some wrong way in my script?

Comment: What does `time` return as sys. time? (i.e., the actual overhead)

Comment: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some modifications, often without speed in mind, I can reduce the processing time by 50% - which is a lot:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="$1"
echo "$filename"
# touch filterfile
totalline=$(wc -l < "$filename")
i=0
j=0
echo "$totalline" lines
while read -r line
do
  i=$((i+1))
  if (( i > ((j+9)) )); then
    j=$i
    echo $i
  fi
  shortline=($(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{6\}\)[ ][0-9]\{6\}.*\([0-9]\{6\}\)[ ][0-9]\{6\}.*/\1 \2/'))
  date1=${shortline[0]}
  date2=${shortline[1]}
  if (( date1 > 700000 ))
  then
    continue
  fi
  d1=$(date -d "$date1" +%s)
  d2=$(date -d "$date2" +%s)
  diffday=$(((d2-d1)/(24*3600)))
  # diffdays=$(date -d $date2 +%s) - $(date -d $date1 +%s))/(24*3600)
  if (( diffday < 30 ))
  then
    echo "$line" >> filterfile
  fi
done < "$filename"
```

Some remarks:

```
# touch filterfile
```

Well - the later `CMD >> filterfile` overwrites this file and creates one, if it doesn't exist.

```
totalline=$(wc -l < "$filename")
```

You don't need awk, here. The filename output is surpressed if wc doesn't see the filename.

Capturing the output in an array:

```
  shortline=($(echo "$line" | sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{6\}\)[ ][0-9]\{6\}.*\([0-9]\{6\}\)[ ][0-9]\{6\}.*/\1 \2/'))
  date1=${shortline[0]}
  date2=${shortline[1]}
```

allows us array access and saves another call to awk.

On my machine, your code took about 42s for 2880 lines (on your machine 2880 s?) and about 19s for the same file with my code.

So I suspect, if you aren't running it on an i486-machine, that cygwin might be a slowdown. It's a linux environment for windows, isn't it? Well, I'm on a core Linux system. Maybe you try the gnu-utils for Windows - the last time I looked for them, they were advertised as gnu-utils x32 or something, maybe there is an a64-version available by now.

And the next thing I would have a look at, is the date calculation - that might be a slowdown too.

2880 lines isn't that much, so I don't suspect that my SDD drive plays a huge role in the game.

Comment: Thank you for your detail explaination and suggestion. I will try your code in my computer. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

This answer does not answer your question but gives an alternative method to your shell script. The answer to your question is given by Sundeep's comment :

[Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Furthermore, you should be aware that everytime you call `sed`, `awk`, `echo`, `date`, ... you are requesting the system to execute a binary which needs to be loaded into memory etc etc. So if you do this in a loop, it is very inefficient.

**alternative solution**

`awk` programs are commonly used to process log files containing timestamp information, indicating when a particular log record was written. `gawk` extended the `awk` standard with time-handling functions. The one you are interested in is :

> **`mktime(datespec [, utc-flag ])`** Turn datespec into a timestamp in the
>   same form as is returned by `systime()`. It is similar to the function
>   of the same name in ISO C. The argument, datespec, is a string of the
>   form "`YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]`". The string consists of six or seven
>   numbers representing, respectively, the full year including century,
>   the month from 1 to 12, the day of the month from 1 to 31, the hour of
>   the day from 0 to 23, the minute from 0 to 59, the second from 0 to
>   60, and an optional daylight-savings flag.
>
> The values of these numbers need not be within the ranges specified;
>   for example, an hour of -1 means 1 hour before midnight. The
>   origin-zero Gregorian calendar is assumed, with year 0 preceding year
>   1 and year -1 preceding year 0. If utc-flag is present and is either
>   nonzero or non-null, the time is assumed to be in the UTC time zone;
>   otherwise, the time is assumed to be in the local time zone. If the
>   DST daylight-savings flag is positive, the time is assumed to be
>   daylight savings time; if zero, the time is assumed to be standard
>   time; and if negative (the default), `mktime()` attempts to determine
>   whether daylight savings time is in effect for the specified time.
>
> If datespec does not contain enough elements or if the resulting time
>   is out of range, `mktime()` returns -1.

As your date format is of the form `yymmdd HHMMSS` we need to write a parser function `convertTime` for this. Be aware in this function we will pass times of the form `yymmddHHMMSS`. Furthermore, using a space delimited fields, your times are located in field `$4$5` and `$11$12`. As `mktime` converts the time to seconds since 1970-01-01 onwards, all we need to do is to check if the delta time is smaller than `30*24*3600` seconds.

```
awk 'function convertTime(t) {
       s="20"substr(t,1,2)" "substr(t,3,2)" "substr(t,5,2)" "
       s=  s substr(t,7,2)" "substr(t,9,2)" "substr(t,11,2)"
       return mktime(s)
     }
     { t1=convertTime($4$5); t2=convertTime($11$12)}
     (t2-t1 < 30*3600*24) { print }' <file>
```

If you are not interested in the real delta time (your sed line removes the actual time of the day), than you can adopt it to :

```
awk 'function convertTime(t) {
       s="20"substr(t,1,2)" "substr(t,3,2)" "substr(t,5,2)" "
       s=  s "00 00 00"
       return mktime(s)
     }
     { t1=convertTime($4); t2=convertTime($11)}
     (t2-t1 < 30*3600*24) { print }' <file>
```

If the dates are not in the fields, you can use `match` to find them :

```
awk 'function convertTime(t) {
       s="20"substr(t,1,2)" "substr(t,3,2)" "substr(t,5,2)" "
       s=  s substr(t,7,2)" "substr(t,9,2)" "substr(t,11,2)"
       return mktime(s)
     }
     { match($0,/[0-9]{6} [0-9]{6}/);
       t1=convertTime(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH));
       a=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
       match(a,/[0-9]{6} [0-9]{6}/)
       t2=convertTime(substr(a,RSTART,RLENGTH))}
     (t2-t1 < 30*3600*24) { print }' <file>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
For my case, the "text" between the first: date and the second date is random for length and content. That's why I am using "sed" to search these two "date" out from the line, then compare them. 
So is it possible to use awk to search the date string and assign it to a variable?

Comment: I found a way to handle it now.
I use "sed" command to fetch the "date" and put it to the beginning of the "line". 
Then I can use your code to filter out the lines I need. 
Then I don't need to use while read

Comment: @TaoHuang I have added a solution for pure `awk` if you don't know the fields.

Comment: Just in case, in awk someone can use FPAT to catch the required fields like this: `awk '{print $1,$3}' FPAT="[0-9]{6}" input-file`